# React. react-avatar-editor package. Change border color

Tags: reactjs

I am using AvatarEditor from react-avatar-editor package and don't understand how to change borders color. I set borders with border prop.

```
    <AvatarEditor
        image={avatar}
        width={297}
        height={313}
        border={10}
        borderRadius={1000}
        color={[0, 0, 0, 0.45]}
        scale={1}
        className={cx('avatar-editor')}
    />
```

Does anybody use this? Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it set is correct. Per the docs , prop `color` should be `Number[]`:

> The color of the cropping border, in the form: [red (0-255), green (0-255), blue (0-255), alpha (0.0-1.0)].